# CSS dropdown menu edit

Tags: html, css

I created the drop-down menu by using CSS and HTML. 
I just can't figure out what am I making wrong. When I hover the mouse over the Social it doesn’t pop-up me the drop-down menu.

Entire fiddle here

[Js Fidle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/t3cho/2j55uthz/)

A part of code where I think its mistake.

```
   #nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul{
    display : block; 
}
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position : absolute ;
    background-color: #333;
    border: 5px solid #222;
    border-top : 0;
    margin-left: -5px;        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youo have `<li><a href="#"> Social</a></li>` and it should be

```
<li><a href="#"> Social</a>
                <ul>
                  <li> Facebook</li>
                  <li> Twitter </li>
                  <li> Youtube </li>
                </ul>
             </li>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2j55uthz/5/)

Comment: Thanks a lot i spend 20 minutes of searching problem in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the sub UL inside the li

```
<li><a href="#"> Social</a>
    <ul>
         <li> Facebook</li>
         <li> Twitter </li>
         <li> Youtube </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

See fidde: http://jsfiddle.net/2j55uthz/1/

The reason is because in your CSS this line:

```
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block
}
```

Is target the UL element *inside* of the hovered li

Answer (score 1):

The `<ul>` containing facebook, youtube, twitter needs to be within the social `<li>`. It works with that change.